# T track application analytic coverage in source code

Tags: java, android

We are using [Adobe's cloud marketing SDK](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/android/dev_qs.html) to collect our application's life cycle metrics. We have been provided by a set of rules that defines what is full analytic coverage status by marketing team and should apply it to our code.

But every once in a while we miss some view or some rule to apply. Since basically this analytics calls are simple methods calls from adobe's SDK object, we have tried to build a tool to help us tracking this calls in right places and reporting any missed rule.

Using [antlr](http://antlr.org/) we created a tool to parse the source code and find where each analytic call has been applied. But we couldn't find any generic solution to find rules that are missed out. Finding each view method would be so style dependent and in case of adding new rules, will be difficult to develop new rules using this tool.

Is there any possible tool or some other method that helps us tracking this analytic function calls and report their absence?